# AngularJS bind complex data model to equivalent UI

Tags: angularjs, typescript

### UPDATE:

I think I found a solution, and I have updated the code below to reflect the latest change. Still, I would like to know if this solution is correct and valid.

---

I'm fairly new to AngularJS, and I'm trying to do something that seems simple enough but I can't get it to work.

I have the following data model (pseudo code):

```
UserDetails:
    UserAddress: Address
    UserBillingInfo: BillingInfo

Address:
    Street: string
    City: string

BillingInfo:
    CreditCardNumber: string
    CardHolderAddress: Address
```

As you can see, I use a common class `Address` twice in different levels.

I also have an HTML snippet to represent each class (using directives), mimicking the structure exactly.

Thing is, I can't get it to bind correctly.

I have a controller, `UserDetailsController` which I bind to at the top level. I want to bind the property `UserAddress` to the address directive and the `UserBillingInfo` property to the billing info directive of the user details directive.
In the billing directive I want to bind the `CardHolderAddress` property to the relevant instance of the address directive.

Nothing I do seems to work.

### source code

#### main.html

```
<userdetails ng-controller="UserDetailsController as ud"></userdetails>
```

#### userdetails.html

```
<addressinput ng-controller="ud.UserAddress as addr"></addressinput>
<billinginfo ng-controller="ud.UserBillingInfo as bill"></billinginfo>
```

#### billinginfo.html

```
<input ng-model="bill.CreditCardNumber" />
<addressinput ng-controller="bill.CardHolderAddress as addr"></addressinput>
```

#### address.html

```
<input ng-model="addr.City" />
<input ng-model="addr.Street" />
```

#### directives.ts

```
module My.Directives {
    'use strict';
    export function addressDirective(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/addressinput.html',
        };
    };
    export function billingDirective(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/billinginfo.html',
        };
    };
    export function userdetailsDirective(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/userdetails.html',
        };
    };
}
```

#### models.ts

```
module My.Models {
    'use strict';
    export class Address {
        public City: string;
        public Street: string;
    }

    export class BillingInfo {
        public CreditCardNumber: string;
        public cardHolderAddress: My.Models.Address;

        constructor() {
            this.cardHolderAddress= new My.Models.Address ();
        }

        public CardHolderAddress = function() { return this.CardHolderAddress; }.bind(this);
    }
}
```

#### controller.ts

```
module My.Controllers {
    'use strict';
    export class UserDetailsController {
        private userAddress: My.Models.Address;
        private userBillingInfo: My.Models.BillingInfo;

        constructor() {
            this.userAddress= new My.Models.Address ();
            this.userBillingInfo= new My.Models.BillingInfo ();
        }

       public UserAddress = function() { return this.userAddress; }.bind(this);
       public UserBillingInfo= function() { return this.userBillingInfo; }.bind(this);
    }
}
```

Itai.